# How to get result from json object with angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a json file and want to count the rows by specific value and load to my page using angular js models.

The json is look like this:

```
[
{"id":"1","district":"AL"," name":"Lisa Lz","gender":"Female"},
{"id":"2","district":"AL"," name":"Arnord Bk","gender":"Male"},
{"id":"3","district":"NY"," name":"Rony Rogner","gender":"Male"}
]
```

The json file loaded by $http service.

How can I run such query on the json data:

```
select COUNT(`name`) as a from tbl_ben where ` gender` = 'Female' and `district` = 'LA';
```

any idea?

Comment: these links may help you ,http://jslinq.codeplex.com/, http://www.jsoniq.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run SQL queries on JSON out-of-the-box, so let's work through it in JavaScript.

We have some data in an array, let's call it `people`:

```
let people = [
    {"id":"1","district":"AL"," name":"Lisa Lz","gender":"Female"},
    {"id":"2","district":"AL"," name":"Arnord Bk","gender":"Male"},
    {"id":"3","district":"NY"," name":"Rony Rogner","gender":"Male"}
];
```

Now, let's filter it down based on their `gender` and `district` like in your query:

```
let filtered = people.filter(p => (p.district === "LA") && (p.gender === "Female"));
```

Now instead of using `COUNT`, we can just check the `length` property of our filtered array:

```
let count = filtered.length;
```

---

We can abstract this code away into a nice function which will do the work for us:

```
let getCount = (array, predicate) => {
    return array.filter(predicate).length;
};
```

And we can then use this function like so:

```
let people = [
    {"id":"1","district":"AL"," name":"Lisa Lz","gender":"Female"},
    {"id":"2","district":"AL"," name":"Arnord Bk","gender":"Male"},
    {"id":"3","district":"NY"," name":"Rony Rogner","gender":"Male"}
];

getCount(people, p => p.district === "NY" && p.gender === "Male"); // 1
```

---

Note that based on your example data, the count is `0` as you have nobody in the district `"LA"`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know that we can't run SQL query on JSON, I just said as an example.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please upvote it and click on the tick icon so others know.